# mySQL query for two disjoint tables

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to combine two SELECT statements on two disjoint tables (t1, t1) into once SELECT statement?  The ideal query statement would return results from both tables when successful or the results if only the t1 query part is successful or the results if only the t2 query part is successful or nothing if the query on t1 and t2 is unsuccessful.

MySQL UNION doesn't work because the tables are disjoint.  JOIN doesn't appear to work because if the query fails for one table the entire query fails.
Test case:

```
create table t1 (
    c11 varchar(2),
    c12 varchar(2),
    c13 varchar(2),
    c14 varchar(2),
    primary key (c11));

create table t2 (
    c21 varchar(2),
    c22 varchar(2),
    c23 varchar(2),
    primary key(c21));

insert into t1 values ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
insert into t2 values ('x', 'y', 'z');
```

Example of what the two distinct SELECT statements:

> SELECT c11, c12, c13, c14 from t1 where c11 = 'a'

Returns a, b, c, d

> SELECT c21, c22, c23 from t2 where c21 = 'x'

Returns x, y, z

Examples of what I am trying to achieve:

> SELECT * (successful query of t1 and t2) where t1.c11 = 'a' and t2.c21 = 'x'

Returns a, b, c, d, x, y, z

> SELECT * (successful query of only t1 and not t2) where t1.c11 = 'a' and t2.c21 = 'v'

Returns a, b, c, d

> SELECT (successful query of only t2 and not t1) where t1.c11 = 'd' and t2.c21 = 'x'

Returns x, y, z

> SELECT (unsuccessful query of both t1 and t2) where t1.c11 = 'd' and t2.c21 = 'v'

Empty set.

Comment: It would be easier if you provide table description , some data examples and expected result

Comment: Table information and data inserted data has been added. The wanted results are part of the examples

Comment: @user2569618 your queries will be maintainable in a stored procedure where you an add comments followed by statements like the ones you specify. Then, it'd be as easy as calling the stored procedure (SP). SP can run the business logic you have defined and result in data you need. I'd definitely go the SP route.

Answer (score 0):

You can just join the tables on a condition which always evaluates true, e.g.

```sql
select c11,c12,c13,c14,c21,c22,c23 from t1
left join t2 on true
where c21='x' and c11='a';
```

Result:

[image: query result]

Kinda hard for me to understand why you want to do this, but there you go. Note that, without the where clause, this query will give as many results as there are rows in t1 multiplied by the number of rows in t2. So if they both have 10 rows, an unconditional query would return 100 results.

Comment: Unfortunately, if the t1.c11 part of the query fails, the entire query fails.  I would still want the the results from the t2.c21 of the query.   I guess I'm looking for an OR condition, two select statements in one query and I would like the results whether one or both select statements succedd.

Comment: I don't understand. Why not use an OR condition then? Your describing exactly what an OR condition does

Comment: How do you OR two select statement into one one query where the results are printed whether one or both select statements succeed?

Comment: select c11,c12,c13,c14,c21,c22,c23 from t1
left join t2 on true
where c21='x' OR c11='a';

Comment: The results of the above query are a permutation of all entries in the t1 and t2.

Comment: ...which is the logically correct result. What other result would you expect?

Comment: I guess you could add `limit 1` if you want one result only